# JSP link submitting data to struts form bean

Tags: jsp, struts-1

I am making a JSP page that links to a page where it will pull a list of data from the database depending on the user who is logged in. I am using a DataSourceRealm type authentication so I pull the username with a `request.geRemoteUser()` and want to submit that to my form when I click the link but I cannot figure out how to do that, my link code is:

```
<li><html:link forward="showEnrolled">View Enrolled Classes</html:link></li>
```

And my form just needs the username to run. Is there anyway I can get it to send the username along with the forward?

Answer (score 0):

checkout this link:

http://www.jguru.com/faq/view.jsp?EID=877089

basically you have to use a HashMap, there are multiple solutions on the above page.